# What is the php curl version of the below curl command

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

What would be the php curl version of the below command

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -H 'Accept: application/json' -d @file.csv [URL]
```

I have the below php curl version which doesn't work

```
$headers = [
   'Content-Type: text/csv',
   'Accept: application/json'
];

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents($filename));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: How does it _"not work"_?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
$headers = [
   'Content-Type: text/csv',
   'Accept: application/json'
];

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ''.$url'');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);

$fp = fopen($file_path, 'r');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: the fopen should use `rb` not `r`, and you have a syntax error on line 8, but otherwise seems good :) (well strictly speaking you should add `echo $response` at the last line because that's what curl does, but that's just nitpicking)

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool to convert cURL command to PHP version of cURL. You can try this website: [curl-toPHP](https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/).

This is the example output using your cURL command.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'your-post-remote');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
    'file' => '@' .realpath('file.csv')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/csv';
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: the @ upload method has been discouraged as of PHP 5.5, disabled-by-default in PHP 5.6, and **COMPLETELY REMOVED** as of PHP 7.0, don't use the @ method, use CURLFile.